# How can I make menemen look better?

Tags: eggs, serving-suggestion

So, there is this famous Turkish dish called [menemen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menemen_(food)). It does not look very appetizing:

[image]

It is prepared using scrambled eggs, tomatoes, green pepper, onion and cheese. [Here is a detailed recipe](https://food52.com/recipes/61974-menemen-turkish-scrambled-eggs-with-tomatoes-and-peppers).

There are some variations which don't use scrambled eggs, but sunny side up eggs, which might be a nice solution. However, the original dish is with scrambled eggs and I don't want to alter the recipe.

Are there any ways to prepare menemen and not make it look like vomit?

Comment: Under different names is quite common in many places at least in the Mediterranean . In Italy is called eggs with salsa .I can look for a photo of a dish or mine if  you want.  My trick is to let a little part of the vegetables in big pieces and let a egg less scrambled. I arrived at this because I agree with you and inspired by photo of israeli tsatshuka

Comment: sprinklings of garnish (cheese, herbs, whatever) can give a different visual context so it doesn't bring up such descriptions even if the actual dish isn't changed underneath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would scramble the eggs, cook, & leave as one solid disc, turning once & allow to brown a bit in the pan, for flavor. Remove it from the pan & cut into 8 slices. Top each slice with the prepared sauce. Garlic sausage on the side. Top with fresh parsley & crumbled feta.

Comment: Ohh, love the solid disk idea for the eggs :).

Comment: I shortly considered a downvote - for me, a solid disk is not the same dish at all. It certainly tastes different than the mixed version, and if somebody were to serve it to me in a reastaurant, I would return it. I get where you are coming from, and maybe the OP will be happy with this solution though.

Answer (score 5):

Without altering the recipe, that's what it'll look like (which I don't think is a bad thing, I like menemen a lot). However, if looks are more important, you could do a French alternative, piperade, instead. Its basically eggs cracked into salsa, rather than salsa added to eggs.

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I meant in my comment to the question.  Well done.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if it looks tasty would be subjective... to me, it looks like a nice, quick comfort-food for cold winter evenings.
But I think I have an idea what you may be looking for :).
What comes to mind is:
Do the scrambled eggs on the side, making sure you season them well -> arrange in a circle to go around your menemen.
For the rest, only use the non-watery part of the tomato, and keep the pieces larger.
Prepare rest as instructed.
Put into the middle of your scrambled eggs.
Enjoy :).